# What is a good book which contains all details of history of special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, resource-recommendations, relativity, history, aether

I am looking for a book which contains all the details of the history of special relativity.That means,I want to know about all those experiments like Michelson and Morley's due to which aether theory was abandoned(a list of them will do),about all the "historical debates"they say in standard books,why Galilean transformations were modified to Lorentz transformations instead of modifying the Maxwell's equations themselves,about the stationary ether theory and stoke's ether-drag theory,and all other abandoned experiments and theories I haven't even heard of,and the reasons of their failures.Is there a book(or any other source) which is dedicated to this topic?If not,where to begin?

Comment: This would be a better question for http://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: Most of what you are asking is included in this book: https://www.mathpages.com/rr/rrtoc.htm  It uses the most simple mathematics possible for each situation (although it can still get a bit tricky in places), and I've found it an absolute goldmine of information.  Can't recommend it highly enough, but you can read it online to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Resnick's [Introduction to Special Relativity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471717258) is concise and somehow comprehensive. For a detailed history of ether theories *before* relativity, you can see Whittaker's [A History of the Theories of Aether & Electricity](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486261263).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expand it to general relativity as well, then Rindler (I used the Second edition of the book titled *Relativity Special, General and Cosmological*) would be a good place to start with.

Answer (score 1):

The best book on the history of Special Relativity is the one by Arthur Miller titled "Albert Einstein’s Special Theory of Relativity: Emergence (1905) and Early Interpretation (1905-1911)"

Here is the Amazon link: [https://www.amazon.com/Albert-Einsteins-Special-Theory-Relativity/dp/0387948708/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=arthur+miller+relativity&qid=1614207375&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387948708)

But you can also find pdf-versions online. I can help if you're interested.